# How to run a background task in Heroku?

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, heroku, request, background-process

I have already build a a python app and deployed  it using `Flask` and `Python`. Here is my Skelton of my code.

```
#app.py
@app.route('/', methods=['GET'])
def login():
    '''login process'''

@app.route('/reset-password', methods=['GET'])
def reset_password():
    '''reset password process'''

@app.route('/add-psa', methods=['GET'])
def add_user():
    '''add user process'''

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.debug = True
    app.run(use_reloader=False, threaded=True)
```

Deployed app work fine in the Heroku. But sometime it takes more than 30 seconds to response which means `H12 error` according to Heroku [doc](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/error-codes#h12-request-timeout). So I followed [this](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/python-rq) tutorial to run background job.
Here is what I've done so far

```
#worker.py
import os

import redis
from rq import Worker, Queue, Connection

listen = ['high', 'default', 'low']

redis_url = os.getenv('REDISTOGO_URL', 'redis://localhost:6379')

conn = redis.from_url(redis_url)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    with Connection(conn):
        worker = Worker(map(Queue, listen))
        worker.work()
```

Next...

```
#utils.py
import requests

def count_words_at_url(url):
    resp = requests.get(url)
    return len(resp.text.split())
```

I also made change in the `Procfile` and `requirements.txt`

I want to run my `reset_password()` in background since its taking more than `30seconds`. Any one who can help me on this?

Comment: The idea with the web-worker nodes is that the Web Dyno receives the request, stores an entry in a queue (redis in this case) so the worker can pick it up and process it. Sorry, I dont have code examples to share

Comment: If you are interested I can post another solution: from the request span a new thread which works in background to process the password reset request (no need of a worker node). The worker makes sense (and it is a lot more elegant) if this is how you are going to process the incoming requests. For one single use case spawning a thread might be simpler

Comment: @BeppeC if you could post solution that would be very helpful to me

Answer (score 4):

A solution is to spawn a thread from the web request: in this case the response can be returned (almost) immediately while a background thread starts and performs the necessary task (without the constraint of the HTTP timeout)

```
# my background thread
class MyWorker():

  def __init__(self, message):
    self.message = message

    thread = threading.Thread(target=self.run, args=())
    thread.daemon = True
    thread.start()

  def run(self):
    logging.info(f'run MyWorker with parameter {self.message}')

    # do something
```

The web request creates an instance of the thread and could inform the caller something is in progress (or apply a different workflow/message)

```
#app.py
@app.route('/reset-password', methods=['GET'])
def reset_password():
'''reset password process'''
   MyWorker('param_value')
   return "In progress... You will receive an email"
```

Comment: If your dyno is asleep does the background task still run?

Comment: A web request wakes up a sleeping Web dyno so the background task can run. If it lasts more than 30 min (and meanwhile there are no web requests) the dyno will stop. If you have a long-running background thread you probably need a different architecture and involve instead a Worker dyno.