# how to run longer than 30 second job on heroku with flask

Tags: flask, heroku

I made a micro web on heroku using flask showing a table with some statistics. It works fine unless I use a button that starts a process of updating statistics. This takes more than 10 minutes as it is downloading data from external database.

Problem is that after half a minute web falls and I got a request timeout error. Here is the log:

```
2021-03-13T08:30:19.764770+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H12 desc="Request timeout" method=POST path="/update" host=vacuumlabs-recruitment-stats.herokuapp.com request_id=13b513e5-a34c-46ec-b224-c0a7d1802394 fwd="78.141.79.60" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=30000ms status=503 bytes=0 protocol=https
2021-03-13T08:31:50.608234+00:00 app[web.1]: [2021-03-13 08:31:50 +0000] [4] [CRITICAL] WORKER TIMEOUT (pid:10)
2021-03-13T08:31:50.609875+00:00 app[web.1]: [2021-03-13 08:31:50 +0000] [10] [INFO] Worker exiting (pid: 10)
2021-03-13T08:31:51.070396+00:00 app[web.1]: [2021-03-13 08:31:51 +0000] [27] [INFO] Booting worker with pid: 27
```

Is there a way how to solve this and let the process run somehow on the background? Thank you in advance for any tips.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need indeed to start a background process when this specific request comes in.
The process is asynchronous therefore you need to decide if/how the response is provided back to the caller (if necessary).

See an example here https://stackoverflow.com/a/64478590/9095551